# There is no existing directory at "/var/www/html/storage/job/12" and its not buildable: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I am having following error into my laravel application while importing file

> There is no existing directory at "/var/www/html/storage/job/12" and its not buildable: Permission denied

I have just configured apache server on Amazon Linux machine

- I have given appropriate permission to apache user.
- I have given chmod 0777 to storage dir

still facing same issue please help me resolve this

Comment: What do you get if you try `ls -l /var/www/html/storage/job/12` ?

Comment: @Zyigh i am getting 
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 133 Sep 10 11:01 data.csv`